# SQL Concatenate strings without duplicate rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have in my table this kind of lines:

```
id  email1             email2                email3             all
1   jean@hotmail.fr    jean@hotmail.fr       jean2@hotmail.fr   NULL
2   herve@hotmail.fr   NULL                  herve@hotmail.fr   NULL
3   pierre@hotmail.fr  NULL                  pierre@gmail.com   NULL
4   roger@hotmail.fr   roger@free.fr         NULL               NULL
5   norbert@hotmail.fr NULL                  norbert@hotmail.fr NULL
6   jules@hotmail.fr   contact@free.fr       julius@gmail.com   NULL
```

With this kind of request:

```
UPDATE mytable SET all=concat_ws(';', email1, email2, email3);
```

I got:

```
id  email1             email2                email3             all
1   jean@hotmail.fr    jean@hotmail.fr       jean2@hotmail.fr   jean@hotmail.fr;jean@hotmail.fr;jean2@hotmail.fr
2   herve@hotmail.fr   NULL                  herve@hotmail.fr   herve@hotmail.fr;herve@hotmail.fr
3   pierre@hotmail.fr  NULL                  pierre@gmail.com   pierre@hotmail.fr;pierre@gmail.com
4   roger@hotmail.fr   roger@free.fr         NULL               roger@hotmail.fr;roger@free.fr
5   norbert@hotmail.fr NULL                  norbert@hotmail.fr norbert@hotmail.fr;norbert@hotmail.fr
6   jules@hotmail.fr   contact@free.fr       julius@gmail.com   jules@hotmail.fr;contact@free.fr;julius@gmail.com
```

But I also need to eliminate duplicates email to optain:

```
id  email1             email2                email3             all
1   jean@hotmail.fr    jean@hotmail.fr       jean2@hotmail.fr   jean@hotmail.fr;jean2@hotmail.fr
2   herve@hotmail.fr   NULL                  herve@hotmail.fr   herve@hotmail.fr
3   pierre@hotmail.fr  NULL                  pierre@gmail.com   pierre@hotmail.fr;pierre@gmail.com
4   roger@hotmail.fr   roger@free.fr         NULL               roger@hotmail.fr;roger@free.fr
5   norbert@hotmail.fr NULL                  norbert@hotmail.fr norbert@hotmail.fr
6   jules@hotmail.fr   contact@free.fr       julius@gmail.com   jules@hotmail.fr;contact@free.fr;julius@gmail.com
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the ideal solution, but you could try `case ... end` clauses to determine duplicates:

```
UPDATE mytable SET all=concat_ws(
     ';'
     , email1
     , case when email2 in (email1) then null else email2 end
     , case when email3 in (email1,email2) then null else email3 end);
```

Comment: Yea, I don't know if it is the best solution, but it works, thanks